# Kotlin: most efficient coroutine based http client

Tags: kotlin, http, client, kotlin-coroutines

What would you suggest as the most efficient coroutine based http client for kotlin (that runs on linux).
One additional requirement is to be also able to limit the number of in progress requests.

Answer (score 1):

[Ktor](https://ktor.io/) is a pretty standard HTTP [client](https://ktor.io/docs/client-dependencies.html) & [server](https://ktor.io/docs/creating-http-apis.html) library (based on coroutines using the [`[CIO]`](https://ktor.io/docs/http-client-engines.html) engine). You can also create a [custom](https://ktor.io/docs/custom-plugins.html) [plugin](https://ktor.io/docs/http-client-plugins.html) which would allow you to limit requests as you see fit.

Comment: yes, i know ktor and http4k as two good wrappers around http libraries (as slf4j did for logging), but i'm actually interested about the underlying library, that actually doesn't pretend it interacts with coroutines, but has the support baked in and is performant enough.

Comment: sounds like ktor is what you want: https://ktor.io/docs/faq.html#cio

"CIO stands for Coroutine-based I/O. Usually we call it to an engine that uses Kotlin and Coroutines to implement the logic implementing an IETF RFC or another protocol without relying on external JVM-based libraries."